# Default color of TopAppBar in jetpack compose material3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I find that the default color of TopAppBar in my project is **white**(in light mode), while normally it should has another default color, like in [document](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary?hl=en#TopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior)).

I notice that the default color in code is:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    colors: TopAppBarColors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(),
    ...
)

@Composable
fun smallTopAppBarColors(
    containerColor: Color = TopAppBarSmallTokens.ContainerColor.toColor(),
    ...
）

internal object TopAppBarSmallTokens {
    val ContainerColor = ColorSchemeKeyTokens.Surface
    ...
}
```

which is the same as that of BottomAppBar, `ColorSchemeKeyTokens.Surface`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BottomAppBar(
    containerColor: Color = BottomAppBarDefaults.containerColor,
    ...
)

object BottomAppBarDefaults {
    val containerColor: Color @Composable get() = BottomAppBarTokens.ContainerColor.toColor()
    ...
}

internal object BottomAppBarTokens {
    val ContainerColor = ColorSchemeKeyTokens.Surface
    ...
}
```

But in my test, container color of `TopAppBar` is the same as document shows, while container color of `TopAppBar` is another: white.

I can't figured out what causes the default color of TopAppBar to turn into white.

Versions of libraies:

- compose: 1.3.0-rc01
- material3: 1.0.0-rc01

Answer (score 1):

The default background color in **M3** `TopAppBar` is based on `containerColor` attribute defined in the `colors` attribute.

The default color is `val ContainerColor = ColorSchemeKeyTokens.Surface`.

Check in your theme. If the `surface` color is omitted the Light scheme default value is: **`#FFFBFE`** as described in the [doc](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/tokens#e26e130c-fa67-48e1-81ca-d28f6e4ed398).

You can check in the code:

```
val Surface = PaletteTokens.Neutral99
val Neutral99 = Color(red = 255, green = 251, blue = 254)
```